# Skip lines/rows which create errors in fread R

Tags: r, fread

I try to read a big file into r. While trying to read it, this error occurs. Even when i skip the first 800607 lines it doesn't disappear. I also tried to delete the line in the terminal with the command.

```
sed '800608d' filename.csv
```

It doesn't solved my problem. I would really appreciate if you could help me.

The original error i got from R is:

```
> data<-fread("filename.csv")
Read 2.0% of 34143409 rows
Error in fread("filename.csv") : 
Field 16 on line 800607 starts with quote (") but then has a problem. It can contain balanced unescaped quoted subregions but if it does it can't contain embedded \n as well. Check for unbalanced unescaped quotes: """The attorney for Martin's family, Benjamin Crump, says the evidence is ""irrelevant\"""" """".","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","Negative"
In addition: Warning message:
 In fread("filename.csv") :
Starting data input on line 8 and discarded previous non-empty line: done
```

Comment: This is a very tricky question. The problem is that you have a column in your file that uses same special characters as the structure of the file (" for quoting, ',' as separator, etc), so it completely messes up file format. The ideal way would be to change the file format, if you have access to the source file, for example, set default quote character as ' instead of ". Otherwise it would be helpful to provide the actual file so that we can take a look at it too

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not allowed to give access, and to change the file format would take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently in the middle of resolving this kind of issue myself. I'm not sure if this will work for all cases--let alone all of the files I'm working with myself. But for now I seem to be getting some successes with:

```
skip.list <- c()

for (i in 1:length(dir(input.dir))){ # i=3
  file <- dir(input.dir)[i]
  ingested.file <- NULL
  ingested.file <- try(fread(paste0(input.dir,file), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F))
  if (class(ingested.file)=="try-error") {
    error.line <-as.integer(sub(" .*","",sub(".*but line ","",as.character(ingested.file))))
    app.reviews.input <- try(fread(paste0(input.dir,file), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F,skip=error.line))
    if (class(ingested.file)=="try-error") {
      skip.list_by.downloads <- c(skip.list_by.downloads, file)
      next
    }
  }
}
```

I'm currently working with about 750 files of 1000 rows each--about 50 of which have the same issue. With this method however, I am able to read in 30 of those 50; the remaining 20 seem to have errors in multiple rows, but I am unable to specify multiple skip values.

If it were possible to specify more skips, then you could try a while-statement. i.e.

`while (class(ingested.file)=="try-error") ...` and then update the error.list as many times as is necessary automatically.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, one last addendum: You may have to change the error.line value depending on what errors you are getting.

Comment: Instead of adding this addendum as a comment, it is better if you [edit] it into your answer. Comments are not guaranteed to be preserved, and some people don't read them. Thank you!